# Find and append data to multiple files in linux

Tags: linux

I have several files in that I need to add the text  "N CHAR(1)," How can I accomplish this in linux without having to do it manually. Thanks

HAVE:

> nullcols
>       (A "to_number(:A,'9')"
>   ,B CHAR(50)
>   )

WANT

> ```
> nullcols 
> (N CHAR(1)
>  ,A "to_number(:A,'9')"
>  ,B CHAR(50) 
> )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it

```
sed -r '/nullcols/{N;s/nullcols\n\(/nullcols\n\(N CHAR\(1\)\n,/;}'
```

Not the most beautiful, but well explained here

[Stack Exchange - using sed to replace a multiline string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string)

Comment: Thanks for the response but the command you have is not making the desired change. It only spits out the original file without making those changes. I'll appreciate if you could look through your command. Thanks

Comment: Hi @user2008558, you typically use sed in 2 ways _sed infile > outfile_ or if you want inline edit add the _-i_ option, so the above would be _sed -i -r 'blah' infile_. Infile will then be modified in place